# MBP 13' HDD in Optical Drive Keeps Unmounting

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hdd

I bought a MacBook Pro 13" late 2011, Yosemite, which had a 256 SSD already installed. I recently installed a 1TB 2.5" SATA3 7200 Hard Drive internal drive in place of my optical drive. The HDD keeps unmounting and have to constantly reformat it because it will not repair. Comes up with message "File system check exit code is 8" & "Code - 36" when coping any type of files. I have triple checked all interior connections. I have attempted repair in Single User Mode fsck to no avail. Adjusted my Sleep Settings.                                                               Is there anything else I could try? Or is it a faulty HDD?

Comment: did you try command-s reboot and then run fsck-y.

Comment: Yep. No dice. I just pulled it and now I'm off to take it back  to whence it came. Going to replace it with a 1TB SSHD...only for a few bucks more. Cheers.

Comment: works for me :)

Comment: Problem solved. It was a dodgy drive. Running like a dream now.